# How to transfer data using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am new to SSIS packages and just require assistance on how to transfer data from one data source onto my own database.

Below is my data flow:

[image]

Now I have a ODBC Source (Http_Requests Source) where I take data from a PostgreSQL database table (see screenshot below for table columns and data):

Below is the OLE DB destination where it has the table I want to transfer the data to (this table is currently blank):

Now I tried to start debugging to extract the data but I get a few errors (displayed below):

[image]

I am a complete novice so I would like some guidance on what I need to include in order to get this SSIS package to transfer data across. Would I need to include a merge statement and how do I apply it. I heard you can write a merge as a proc and call on the proc as a sql command. Does that mean I will need to write a proc in SSMS and then call on it within the OLE DB Destination?

If somebody can provide an example and screenshot then that would be very helpful as I am really new to SSIS.

Thank you,

Comment: You can enable 'Delay Validation' as true

Comment: Try checking the "Keep Identity" box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check constraint on destination table or disable them before running it.
Below are query you can use.
-- Disable all table constraints
ALTER TABLE YourTableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
-- Enable all table constraints
ALTER TABLE YourTableName CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

Answer (score 0):

Tick keep identity
box or drop primary key on the table. After you apply the changes do not forget to refresh metadata by opening the mappings in sis.

Answer (score 0):

the error means that PerformanceId is an IDENTITY column on your destination table.  IDENTITY columns are read only unless you tell it otherwise.  So if we were in tSQL to be able to insert IDENTITY we would turn on IDENTITY_INSERT.  Because you are in SSIS you can accomplish the same thing by checking the "keep identity" box.

**HOWEVER** when ever you get *an error like this it is usually a sign that you should NOT be mapping ID to Performance ID*.  The question you have to ask is the Identity from your source supposed to be the identity of the destination table?  Usually not, most of the time it would be another column as a surrogate key.  Then you have to understand if it is even possible.  because if there is a unique constraint or primary key then the identity cannot repeat which means you have to know that your source's id column will not cause a duplicate primary key violation.

More than likely the actual fix if for you to uncheck ID from the source and ignore the value.

Answer (score 0):

The column PerformanceID  (in the target) is almost certainly an identity column and that is why it is not working. You may not want to transfer it (and have SQL Server generate values for PerformanceID or you can check 'Keep Identity.'